# Why does my HTML page re-draw, replacing my input?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn a little Javascript. I wrote the code below expecting to see the contents of the text box written to the page when the button is clicked. This does happen but very briefly as the page seems to redraw back to it's original values.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
    function getData() {
        var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
        document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Playing with Javascript and Forms</h1>

<form id="myForm">
    Name: <input type="input" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick = "getData()">
</form>

<p id="space"></p>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies, very helpful. I can't vote up yet my reputation is rock bottom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does this because the form is being fully submitted and the page reloads. To stop it, change the onclick to:

```
onClick = "return getData()"
```

and your function to return false with:

```
function getData() {
    var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = x;
    return false;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TXEa9/)**

This will prevent the form from submitting and allow your code to run.

Answer (score 1):

Your form submits. To avoid it try adding `return false` at the end of "getData" function and change `onClick = "getData()"` to `onClick = "return getData()"`

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6gAkL/**

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript seems to be working fine.
The problem is after the JS is ran the HTML kicks in and submits the form POSTing it's data to the POST target (None as currently set).
If you don't want the form to be posted when you click that input you probably should remove the:     type="submit"

Edit:
This would be most appropiate: 
    < input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick = "getData()" >